# I installed packages by pip in Blender 2.83, but it is impossible to import them

Tags: python

I'm Japanese and sorry for my poor English.

I'm making an mathematical program which will work on Blender 2.83. Thus, I need to install 3rd party modules to my Blender 2.83 python (e.g. scipy, sympy, etc..).

So, I successfully installed them by pip, following instructions [here](https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/how-to-install-required-packages-to-the-blender-python-with-pip/) or using terminal commands below.

```
C:\Windows\system32> "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\python\bin\python.exe" -m pip install --user -U scipy
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-1.6.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (32.6 MB)
   |████████████████████████████████| 32.6 MB 3.3 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.23.0,>=1.16.5 in c:\program files\blender foundation\blender 2.83\2.83\python\lib\site-packages (from scipy) (1.17.0)
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-1.6.2
    
C:\Windows\system32> "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\python\bin\python.exe" -m pip install --user -U sympy
Collecting sympy
  Downloading sympy-1.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.9 MB)
   |████████████████████████████████| 5.9 MB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting mpmath>=0.19
  Downloading mpmath-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (532 kB)
   |████████████████████████████████| 532 kB 6.8 MB/s
Installing collected packages: mpmath, sympy
  WARNING: The script isympy.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed mpmath-1.2.1 sympy-1.7.1
```

But, I can't import these modules, in neither python console nor text editor of Blender 2.83.

```
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
   2.83File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

However, I found that these modules are not installed at

> C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender
> 2.83\2.83\python\lib\site-packages

, but

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts

by trying to reinstall these packages.

```
C:\Windows\system32> "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\python\bin\python.exe" -m pip install scipy
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\UserName\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (1.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.23.0,>=1.16.5 in c:\program files\blender foundation\blender 2.83\2.83\python\lib\site-packages (from scipy) (1.17.0)
```

How do I fix this problem ?