# Blender python doesn't recognize installed packages when ran in Blender

Tags: python, scripting

I've recently installed Blender on a new PC and installed packages for python I use for dataviz. However, for whatever reason when Blenders python is executed within Blender it doesn't recognize them. But if it's executed in a console it does. I've never experienced this before.

Here we are executing python in a command console. Note the location

[image]

And here it is in Blender

[image]

the capitalized 'EXE' is a bit sus and I don't think that should matter, but it's kinda interesting.

Here is import without problem in console

[image]

In Blender

[image]

This also may be of interest, but when I exit Blender I always get Freed Memory error. Could this be causing an issue?

[image]

EDIT: Found a temporary fix here: [I installed packages by pip in Blender 2.83, but it is impossible to import them](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218700/i-installed-packages-by-pip-in-blender-2-83-but-it-is-impossible-to-import-them)

But I have to do it each time blender restarts

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\***\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages")
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on Windows.

Solution: **Ensure administrator permissions when using `pip`**